# Как избежать окна выбора принтера

Tags: java, принтер

Не знаю как сделать печать без диалога выбора принтера

```
import java.awt.*;

public class PrintApp  extends Frame{

    public PrintApp(){
        Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        PrintJob printJob=toolkit.getPrintJob(this,"Printing test",null);
        if(printJob!=null){
            Graphics graphics=printJob.getGraphics();
            graphics.drawString("Test printing in Java",10,10);
            printJob.end();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        new PrintApp();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11801159/2110496

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода:

```
public class printWithoutDialog implements printable 
{
    public PrintService findPrintService(String printerName)
    {
        for (PrintService service : PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices())
        {
            if (service.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName))
                return service;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException 
    {
        if (page > 0) { /* У нас только одна страница, а отсчёт начинается с нуля*/
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        /* Чтобы избежать обрезания нужно преобразовать X/Y в PageFormat */
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        /* Рендерим контент */
        g.setFont(new Font("Roman", 0, 8));
        g.drawString("Hello world !", 0, 10);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public printSomething(String printerName)
    {
        // Находим PrintService по имени
        PrintService ps = findPrintService(printerName);                                    
        // Создаём задание для печати
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();            

        job.setPrintService(ps);      
        // Выставляем printable
        job.setPrintable(this);                
        // Инициируем печать
        job.print();
    }
}
```

Чтобы печатать в Java без диалога, нужно выбрать `PrintService` для `PrinterJob`.
Класс `PrintService` предоставляет доступ к желаемому принтеру.

Класс выше реализует интерфейс `printable` так же, как это сделано в туториалах Java(с диалогом). Разница только в методе `printSomething`(Поиск сервиса по имени принтера и установка его в созданный `PrinterJob`).

---

[Источник на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496044/2110496)

Comment: Не могу задать ширину, больше 72 не делается в этом примере. `Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setSize(600,600);
        paper.setImageableArea(300,300,500,600);
        pf.setPaper(paper);`